# TypeScript indicate .ts(7053) error when update object by square brackets

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I would like to update an object using square brackets, previously I would like to check if update is allowed.

Here is my code:

```
const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
const allowedUpdates = ['phone', 'email', 'company', 'metadata'];
const user = USERS.find((user) => userId === user.id);
updates.forEach((update) => user[update] = req.body[update]);
```

User class:

```js
export class User {
    constructor(public id: string, public firstName: string, public lastName: string, 
        public phone: string, public email: string, public company: string, metadata?: object){
    };
}
```

Then the following error occurs:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'User'. No index signature with a
> parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'User'.ts(7053)

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Please send your `User` class.

Comment: @Aplet123 sure, I forgot. Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to do some aggressive typecasting, as well as fixing some of the logic of your code:

```js
export class User {
  // this is filler
  public id: number = 1;
  // you forgot to put a public in front of metadata
  constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string, 
    public phone: string, public email: string, public company: string, public metadata?: object){
  };
}

// these 3 lines are also filler
const USERS: User[] = [];
const req = {body: {phone: "asdf", firstName: "foo"} as object};
const userId = 1;

const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
// use a set since it's faster
const allowedUpdates: Set<string> = new Set(['phone', 'email', 'company', 'metadata']);
const user = USERS.find((user) => userId === user.id);
// make sure to actually filter updates
// at this point, you can be sure that every element is in keyof User
const filteredUpdates: (keyof User)[] = updates.filter((update) => allowedUpdates.has(update)) as (keyof User)[];
// user could be undefined if none is found, so we need to check for that
if (user) {
  filteredUpdates
    // you might not need the "as keyof typeof req.body" cast here
    .forEach((update) => user[update] = req.body[update as keyof typeof req.body]);
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Let  me understand it, I will analyze your code :)

Comment: it almost works. Now I have following error: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322) at the same place as earlier. The interesting thing is: when I remove "public" keyword next to metadata under User class then everything is ok.